# Typescript - Make class properties unavailable until user logs in

Tags: typescript, conditional-types

I want the properties of my main class to be null until after the user calls the `login()` method. I can't put this in the constructor since it is an asynchronous method.

I know that it involves adding a generic property to the class, but I am having trouble configuring it correctly.

```
import api from "./api"
import {RSS, User} from "./endpoints"

type isLoggedIn<B extends boolean, T> = B extends true ? T : null

export default class MyApi<B extends boolean = false> {
    private loggedIn: B
    //This is needed for other properties, but you must login to get it
    private accessToken: string 
    public rss: isLoggedIn<B, RSS>
    public user: isLoggedIn<B, User> 
    //There are a lot more properties, but they generally look like this ^

    constructor(private clientId: string, private clientSecret: string) {}

    public login = async () => {
        const auth = await api.get("oauth url", {client_id: this.clientId, client_secret: this.clientSecret, grant_type: "client_credentials"})
        this.accessToken = auth.access_token

        //With the accessToken, the other properties can be initialized
        this.rss = new RSS(this.accessToken) as isLoggedIn<B, RSS>
        this.user = new User(this.accessToken) as isLoggedIn<B, User>

        this.loggedIn = true as B //???
    }

}
```

The main problem is that the generic type in the class never becomes true, it always stays at the default (false). I don't know how I would make it true after running the `login()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using only types, it relys on you reusing a instance that is signed in,

private constructor because then you can control the return type.
create method as new constructor with return type changed

```
type MyApiNoAuth = Omit<MyApi, Exclude<keyof MyApi, "login">>
class MyApi {
  private loggedIn = false;

  private constructor(private clientId: string, private clientSecret: string) { }
  static create(clientId: string, clientSecret: string): MyApiNoAuth {
    return new MyApi(clientId, clientSecret)
  }

  public login = () => {
    // do whatever you want here.
    return this; // needed to be last line here
  }

  public next = () => {
    return "next";
  }
  public othermethod = () => "";
}



const test = new MyApi(); // fails can't instantiate like this. (good)
const test1 = MyApi.create("clientId", "clientSecret"); // works good
const test2 = MyApi.create("clientId", "clientSecret").next(); // can't call this instance hasn't called login.
const test3 = MyApi.create("clientId", "clientSecret").login(); // this is the instance class we will use

test3.next() // great. works
test3.othermethod() // great works because we've logged in in this instance.
```

Comment: I had no idea that you could make the constructor private! I modified your example a little bit so that I instantiate the class with with `myApi = await MyApi.login("id", "secret");`, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a slightly different approach.

Since the compiler has no way of knowing that the login method has been called, you need to add a member that checks if the user has logged in and propagates a corresponding type change to the typechecker.

This can be accomplished via a type guard.

```
type IsLoggedIn<B extends boolean, T> = B extends true ? T : never;

export default class MyApi<B extends boolean = false> {
  isLoggedIn(): this is MyApi<true> {
    return this.loggedIn;
  }

  rss: IsLoggedIn<B, RSS>;
  user: IsLoggedIn<B, User>;
}
```

Given the above, we can write

```
async function useApi(api: MyApi<boolean>) {
  await api.login();

  if (api.isLoggedIn()) {
    api.user.// etc.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately the type I am getting with this approach is `myApi<false> & myApi<true>`. But don't worry about it, I decided against adding this feature since it's way too complicated for me to implement.

Comment: It shouldn't be, but it can be revised to fix that

Comment: @Tenpi the problem was the default of `false`. Checkout the update